# Multer multiple uploads fail and initial upload comes in three times

Tags: node.js, express, upload, fs, multer

I am unable to upload a second file after the first goes through successfully. Using this route...

```
var multer = require('multer');

var upload = multer({dest: 'base-images/'});
var type = upload.single('file');

app.post('/admin/upload', type, function(req, res) {

    //Get the temporary directory/file name
    var tmp_path = req.file.path;
    console.log(tmp_path); //'base-images/1d7608bb0b570c7fcf669315c6f31401'

    //Create a new filename based on time
    var now = new Date();
    var timeID = Number(now);
    var newName = timeID + ".jpg";
    console.log(newName); //'1476740040280.jpg'

    //Convert the random Multer name to my newName
    fs.rename(tmp_path, 'base-images/'+newName, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        fs.stat('base-images/'+newName, function (err, stats) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('stats: ' + JSON.stringify(stats));
            res.send("Done"); //Works the first time, not on subsequent ones.
            //stats {"dev":16777218,"mode":33188,"nlink":1,"uid":502,"gid":20,"rdev":0,"blksize":4096,"ino":19058190,"size":101269,"blocks":200,"atime":"2016-10-17T21:33:22.000Z","mtime":"2016-10-17T21:33:22.000Z","ctime":"2016-10-17T21:33:22.000Z","birthtime":"2016-10-17T21:33:22.000Z"}
        });
    });
});
```

So when the image goes through the first time, it works as expected. If I go select another image and send it through I get an `Error: Unexpected field` and then about two minutes later a second version of that original image shows up with a new value for `newName`. Then a minute later, another copy of that original image shows up with yet another version of `newName`. It seems to stop after the third time.

My goal is to be able to upload images, multiple would be nice, and have their names set to the timestamp that the server processes them.

**UPDATE 1: Trying with multer.diskstorage()**

I've rewritten it like so trying to incorporate diskstorage as mentioned below.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
           cb(null, 'base-images/');
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
           var now = new Date();
           var timeID = Number(now);
           var newName = timeID + ".jpg";
           cb(null, newName);
      }
 });

 var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file');

app.post('/admin/upload', function(req, res) {

    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error Occurred');
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(req.file);
        res.send('Your File Uploaded');
        console.log('Photo Uploaded');
    })
});
```

Three things happen when written like this.

First, initial file upload goes through as expected.

Second, without refreshing .html, trying another file upload throws `Error Occurred` with the following log...

```
{ [Error: Unexpected field]
   code: 'LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE',
   field: 'file',
   storageErrors: [] }
```

Third, without refreshing, a third attempt throws...

```
fs.js:975
  binding.unlink(pathModule._makeLong(path), req);
          ^

TypeError: path must be a string
```

Requirements are that I be able to upload multiple files, one at a time, without refreshing the page.

Comment: There is a response in /admin/upload route??

Comment: Apologies. Updated original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  this instead of fs.rename  (I haven't tested this code,some errors are possible)

```
  var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: 'base-images/',
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
       var now = new Date();
       var timeID = Number(now);
       var newName = timeID + ".jpg";
       cb(null, newName);
    }
  })

 var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated code above to reflect these changes and describe new set of errors.